# How to differentiate between multiple elements with the same class using xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

In my tester I am searching for the different xpaths of some elements that are using the same id, class and other attributes. They are exaclty the same except for their order. I am trying to find out each ones xpath, but all that I find is three elements when I search for this xpath: `//input[@id='group[2][325]']`. When I tried to find the first element of the three found elements like this `//input[@id='group[2][325]'][1]` I also just get the same three elements. So isn't there anyway to get a specific element from the three found elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case there are multiple elements matching

```py
//input[@id='group[2][325]']
```

XPath you can use

```py
(//input[@id='group[2][325]'])[1]
```

to get the first element.
In the similar way, the n-th element gan be get with

```py
(//input[@id='group[2][325]'])[n]
```

XPath locator.

Comment: The "(" was what I missed I see. Huge thanks!

Comment: Not exactly.  `(//input[@id='group[2][325]'])[1]` and `//input[@id='group[2][325]'][1]` are both correct syntaxes, doing different things.